# How to convert my python code into python module?

Tags: python

As i made one project called card scanning which is used to extract the accurate data from card using pytesseract and OPENCV so i have completed that and i want to convert my code into python module i'm empty about that so can anyone explain how do i proceed this and suggest some links for me.

This is my python code:

```
import re
import requests as req
# import Flask as Flask
import imutils
# from flask import Flask,render_template,request,json,jsonify
import cv2
import os
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, json
import uuid
app = Flask(__name__)
BINARY_THREHOLD = 180
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
# Start
# make a UUID based on the host ID and current time
@app.route('/',methods=['post','get'])
def main():
    return render_template("start.html")
@app.route('/start',methods=['POST','GET'])
def start():
    print("stay")
    if request.files['attachement']:
        target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'static/files')
        print(target)
        # os.makedirs(target)
        file = request.files['attachement']
        print(file)
        filename = file.filename
        destination = "/".join([target, filename])
        print(destination)
        file.save(destination)
        base = os.path.basename(destination)
        print(base)
        oriimage = cv2.imread(destination)
        newimage = cv2.resize(oriimage,(984,582))
        # cv2.imshow("iiihufasfva",newimage)
        # dob=cv2.imread(newimage)
        # cv2.imshow("dob",newimage)
        dob=cv2.imread(destination)
        cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/shruthipriyanka/PycharmProjects/Scanning/newone.png",newimage)
        imgray1 = cv2.cvtColor(newimage,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        ret2,threshone = cv2.threshold(imgray1,139,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/shruthipriyanka/PycharmProjects/Scanning/threshone.png",threshone)
        single=Image.open("C:/Users/shruthipriyanka/PycharmProjects/Scanning/threshone.png")
        singlejoin=pytesseract.image_to_string(single,lang='eng',config='--tessdata-dir "C://Tesseract-OCR//tessdata"')
        print(singlejoin)
        fetchdate=re.findall("\d{2}/+\d{2}/+\d{4}",singlejoin)
        print(fetchdate)
        lofetch=[]
        for dd in fetchdate:
            print(dd)
            duty=re.split("/",dd)
            print(duty)
            lofetch.append(dd)
        print(lofetch)
        print(lofetch[0])

        # name
        singlenamepart = newimage[110:180, 190:650]
        cv2.imshow("singlenamepart", singlenamepart)
        singlenamepartgray = cv2.cvtColor(singlenamepart, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        ret2, threshsingle = cv2.threshold(singlenamepartgray, 189, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/shruthipriyanka/PycharmProjects/Scanning/singlenamepart.png", singlenamepart)
        singlenamepartopen = Image.open("C:/Users/shruthipriyanka/PycharmProjects/Scanning/singlenamepart.png")
        singlenameparttrain = pytesseract.image_to_string(singlenamepartopen, lang='eng',
                                                      config='--tessdata-dir "C://Tesseract-OCR//tessdata"')
        print("singlenameparttrain:", singlenameparttrain)
        # namesecond
        namesecond = newimage[150:210, 190:650]
        cv2.imshow("singlenamepart", namesecond)
        namesecondpartgray = cv2.cvtColor(namesecond, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        ret2, threshsingle = cv2.threshold(namesecondpartgray, 189, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/shruthipriyanka/PycharmProjects/Scanning/namelysecond.png", namesecond)
        nome = Image.open("C:/Users/shruthipriyanka/PycharmProjects/Scanning/namelysecond.png")
        nometrain = pytesseract.image_to_string(nome, lang='eng',
                                                          config='--tessdata-dir "C://Tesseract-OCR//tessdata"')
        print("nome:", nometrain)

        # address
        adress = newimage[260:350, 350:950]
        cv2.imshow("adress", adress)
        adresspartry = cv2.cvtColor(namesecond, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        ret2, threshsingle = cv2.threshold(adresspartry, 189, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/shruthipriyanka/PycharmProjects/Scanning/ado.png", adress)
        addadd = Image.open("C:/Users/shruthipriyanka/PycharmProjects/Scanning/ado.png")
        adding = pytesseract.image_to_string(addadd, lang='eng',
                                                config='--tessdata-dir "C://Tesseract-OCR//tessdata"')
        print("adding:", adding)

        # dateofbirth
        datyformat = dob[165:225, 190:650]
        cv2.imshow("datyformat", datyformat)
        nametwogray = cv2.cvtColor(datyformat, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        ret2, threshnametwo = cv2.threshold(nametwogray, 135, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/shruthipriyanka/PycharmProjects/Scanning/datyformat.png", datyformat)
        datyformatopen = Image.open("C:/Users/shruthipriyanka/PycharmProjects/Scanning/datyformat.png")
        datyformattrainone = pytesseract.image_to_string(datyformatopen, lang='eng',
                                                         config='--tessdata-dir "C://Tesseract-OCR//tessdata"')
        print("nameone:", datyformattrainone)
        dateformatone = re.findall('\d{2}/+\d{2}/+\d{4}', datyformattrainone)
        print(dateformatone)
        datepart = dob[195:300, 190:950]
        cv2.imshow("datepart", datepart)
        datepartgray = cv2.cvtColor(datepart, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        ret2, datepartnametwo = cv2.threshold(datepartgray, 135, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/shruthipriyanka/PycharmProjects/Scanning/datepart.png", datepartnametwo)
        datepartopen = Image.open("C:/Users/shruthipriyanka/PycharmProjects/Scanning/datepart.png")
        dateparttrain = pytesseract.image_to_string(datepartopen, lang='eng',
                                                    config='--tessdata-dir "C://Tesseract-OCR//tessdata"')
        print("datepart:", dateparttrain)

        dateformat = re.findall('\d{2}/+\d{2}/+\d{4}', dateparttrain)
        print(dateformat)
        dateformatstring=re.findall('\d+',dateparttrain)
        print(dateformatstring)

        if dateformatone:
            aa = dateformatone
            print(aa)
        elif dateformat:
            aa = dateformat
            print(aa)
        # singlecharacter
        singlepart = newimage[200:290, 350:950]
        cv2.imshow("singlepart",singlepart)
        singlepartgray = cv2.cvtColor(singlepart, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        ret2, threshsingle = cv2.threshold(singlepartgray, 189, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/shruthipriyanka/PycharmProjects/Scanning/singlepart.png",singlepart)
        singlepartopen=Image.open("C:/Users/shruthipriyanka/PycharmProjects/Scanning/singlepart.png")
        singleparttrain=pytesseract.image_to_string(singlepartopen,lang='eng',config='--tessdata-dir "C://Tesseract-OCR//tessdata"')
        print("singlecharar:",singleparttrain)
        def upperOnly(s):
            onlyCaps = ""
            for char in s:
                if char.isupper() == True:
                    onlyCaps += char
            return onlyCaps
        upper=upperOnly(singleparttrain)
        print(upper)
        singlele=[]
        for pos in singleparttrain:
            singlele.append(pos)
            print(pos)
        print(singlele)
        carddid = "CardID" + '_' + uuid.uuid4().hex[:4].upper()
        print("Pass_ID:", carddid)
        gen=""
        for ap in singlele:
            if ap=="F"or"f":
                gen="Female"
                print(gen)
                pass
            elif ap=="M"or"m":
                gen="Male"
                print(gen)
                pass
            elif ap!="F"and"M":
                gen="Female"

            # elif ap=="F" and "M":
            #     gen="female"
            #     print(gen)

        datas = {"paasid": carddid, "name": nometrain,
                 "surname": singlenameparttrain, "addtwo": adding, "dob": lofetch[0], "gender": gen}
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: As a package intended to be used by other code (most packages are), this wouldn't be too useful because it spawns a webserver and has lots of paths in it that are dependent on your machine. You'll want to pull those out and create a package that only has the core behavior with some sane API  to use it (say a function called `extract_card_data` that takes a PIL image and returns a dictionary with the card's data).

Comment: Thank you @Bailey Parker i will try to do like Ur suggestion

Comment: @Bailey Parker i tried to load image dynamically but it is not working  can you suggest how can i access user filename from anywhere in python.

Comment: I don't fully understand your code. If it works as is you should post it on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get some help cleaning it up. Only after then would I start thinking about making it a package.

Comment: Actually i made a project for passport book scanning to extract the details from the card this code well worked for me..shall i know which part u cant understand.

Comment: All of it. It's basically 167 lines that's one method and none of it is PEP8.  There are hard coded paths and magic numbers. The comments are sparse. You just aren't going to find many SO users with the patience to comb through all of that. Again, I'd recommend posting on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: i have posted in code review @Bailey Parker